# Android Kill Service when I press Clear Memory

Tags: android

I have seted a service and it use start Forground , so android will not kill it , but when I press Clear Memory in task manager , it will close my service , where is problem , if you tr this with build in media player , android will not kill it at all

I have use start_stricky and Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE

if I use NO_CLEAR , there is not diffrence

how can I solve this problem ?

thanks

Comment: @Jay no there is likely to relation at all.  Your problem sounds more like an electrical noise problem, if you want to pursue it, it needs its own question, so please delete your comment here (or if someone else deletes it, feel free to remove this too)

Comment: I just used a oscilloscope with a visual output and the noise seemed regular. I even tried turning on the A/C and Heat at the same time to see if there was a possibility of faulty circuitry on the vehicle and there is no such indication. You earned a down vote. :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether the service is killed and restart it.
See the following answers:

> - [How to restart the Service Automatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707081/how-to-restart-the-service-automatically-in-android)
> - [Android - how to make sure my Service is restarted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607861/android-how-to-make-sure-my-service-is-restarted)
> - [Android: How to auto-restart application after it's been "force closed"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681499/android-how-to-auto-restart-application-after-its-been-force-closed)

Comment: Please stop providing answers in links. Coz links may be removed in future

Comment: @Agarwal - those are all links to questions here on SO.  It's better to reference the existing questions than paraphrase or copy their answers.

Comment: @AgarwalShankar though i tend to agree with you, it is this site's policy that answers to questions (when used as part of an answer) MUST be referenced via link and never paraphrased.  i was severely rebuked for posting the same answer to different questions, even though the answer was correct in all cases.  it was called SPAMMING by the moderators.